# Rotating Monkey Head Example in Kivy does not render

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to complete the [example on the Kivy website that shows how to display a 3D obj file](https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__3Drendering__main__py.html) of a monkey head out of Blender. I was able to get their source code to run without errors (only getting `Info` lines in output) but when the Renderer comes up the window is blank (just the black background).  I checked to make sure I had selected the monkey head in Blender before exporting.  Does anyone know what might be causing this?

(adding printout from python shell)

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Edward\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-05-02_2.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4276>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Intel(R) HD Graphics>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <4.00 - Build 10.18.10.4276>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO              ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO              ] [Shader      ] Read <simple.glsl>
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

Comment: have you tried it with the [example files on github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/3Drendering)? This works for me. If it doesn't for you, please post logs.

Comment: Hi zeeMonkeez, thanks for your help.  I tried the github files but still get blank screen in the renderer.  I added the shell printout to question.

Comment: from my experience I'd say it has something to do with the Shader. Plz post contents of simple.glsl so we can take a look.